# Force QBENCHMARK to perform several iterations

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtestlib

How can I perform several iterations using `QBENCHMARK`?

For example I have this code:

```
void MyUnitTest::speedText()
{
    QBENCHMARK {
        obj->foo();
    }
}
```

I looked at the documentation, and it says:

> The code inside the QBENCHMARK macro will be measured, and possibly also repeated several times in order to get an accurate measurement. This depends on the selected measurement back-end.

I tried with the default and `-tickcounter`, but both show only one iteration:

Default (no args):

```
RESULT : MyUnitTest::speedText():
     89 msecs per iteration (total: 89, iterations: 1)
```

With `-tickcounter`:

```
RESULT : MyUnitTest::speedText():
     210,246,493 CPU ticks per iteration (total: 210,246,493, iterations: 1)
```

The other 2 don't work - `-callgrind` is Linux-only while `-eventcounter` seems to cause the unit test to terminate.

So is there a way to make `QBENCHMARK` do more than one iteration?

Comment: I think the QBENCHMARK will only run more than once if timerange would be immeasurable

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I thought it would run it at least a few times to show the effects of caching (first run versus the average). I guess I could just simulate it by repeating the `QBENCHMARK` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QBENCHMARK` runs only once so long as the elapsed time for the iteration exceeds some fixed threshold (the threshold depends on the chosen backend).

In order to force `QBENCHMARK` to perform several iterations you will need to set the [command line option](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest-overview.html#benchmarking-options) `-iterations 10`.